# When we talk of functional macromolecules (e.g. proteins as enzymes, hormones, receptors, antibodies etc), towards what are they evolving?�

Tags: evolution, molecular-evolution

Actually this is a question which is given in a book and to be honest,it has baffled me.I'm not so much well versed with molecular evolution so my guess would be,say some sort of enzyme which could catalyse more than 1 reaction maybe coz then that 1 will be sufficient enough to do much more work,like it happens at organismic level,like reduction in legs of prawns and shrimps which has happened (earlier relatives has more legs but they were less effective as compared to their modern counterparts).So,my guess would be something like that but as I said earlier,I'm not so good in molecular evolution so please help me out.Or tell me about what were the characteristics or primitive macromolecules and those that occur today and via that,this question might be explained.Also,I've written the question as such given in the book i.e without any changes.

Comment: This is a nonsensical question akin to asking you to predict the future. Sure, further evolution of proteins etc may occur, but there is no “master plan”. Whatever TBH is should be ashamed of itself. I vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a false assumption.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please [edit] it? Add more relevant details if necessary.

Comment: Well,can you explain that what are the changes that anyone have observed in the macromolecules of say the Proterozoic era or Palaeozoic era and the macromolecules that occur today.I guess that the book might be asking for this.........

Comment: "I guess that the book might be asking..." is not good enough. Please edit your question with a direct quotation from the book and naming the book, author and publisher. In addition please remove the non-unicode, non-isolatin character at the end of your title and explain what TBH is quoting from that (or delete any mention of it). As I have already commented, the question as you pose it is in my opinion based on a false assumption, namely that evolution is directed "towards" something. If this was only your interpretation of a book, then we can help you if we know what was written.

Comment: I think that TBH means to be honest,Read what I've written carefully,I've expressed my view that I myself was baffeled.Also,I've written the exact question of the book as such without making any changes i.e. the question has been copied word by word.The book is NCERT Exemplar problems and the chapter is evolution.I guess that you might be able to find a PDF of this somewhere on the internet.Also, isn't evolution is directed towards making us fitter for survival as quoted by Darwin in his book survival of the fittest.

Comment: So the title of your question (complete with dodgy character) is a quotation from a book of exam questions? This was in no way clear, and should have been stated in quotes in the question. What is clear is there is no reason for me to change my attitude to your question, or for you to spend any more time on such the flawed question in the book. One word of advice if you are approaching an exam. Use standard English (“coz” is not), divide your writing into paragraphs, and do not use text abbreviations. Unless you deliberately wish to antagonise the examiners towards you.

Comment: I mean I know this seems kinda wacky but this is the only explanation I could think of.Also,I'm kinda new on this website so can you give me some advice about posting question and writing the body please.